# Apply web config settings for a specific page only

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have the following config that I would like to remove from web config and only enforce in code for a certain page 'Page1.aspx', else the configuration would apply across all pages.

**How would I specify this configuration or enforce it through code, so it applies to only Page1.aspx?**

```
<system.web>
  <browserCaps>
    <case>
        RequiresControlStateInSession=true
    </case>
  </browserCaps>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you want to have this settings in code, or apply them to a file, or both? This is different things.

Comment: My goal is to apply this to a single page Page1.aspx. I am open to using code or some special configuration to achieve this goal. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a way to mention configuration on a page basis, so the configuration only applies to that page.

Just include any specific configuration under a `<location>` element that you would like to apply to a single page. Keep the following points in mind when using this approach:

- Set an appropriate value for the `path` attribute of the `<location>` element. It can be a relative path.
- The `<location>` element must be outside the `<system.web>`, `<system.webserver>`, and any other sections within *Web.config*.

In my case the following worked, where I specified a `<location>` section for the single page for which I wanted to specify special configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<!-- all sections in web config go here. Put the Location elements always 
 at end of your web config file -->
  <location path="Page1.aspx">
   <system.web>
    <browserCaps>
     <case>
       RequiresControlStateInSession=true
     </case>
    </browserCaps>
   </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: @abatishchev, Thanks for your participation and help.